# zk-How to pass label value from controller class to zul in zk

Tags: controller, zk, zul

I want to pass the value of the Label from the controller class to zul page. But the label value which Iam setting in the controller class is not displayed in the UI. Kindly help me to solve this. Below is my code.

**zul page :**

```
<zk>
    <window title="sampleModal"
        closable="true" position="center,center" id="calendarModal"
        action="show: slideDown;hide: slideUp" width="75%" height="100%"
        style="background-color: white;position: absolute;z-index: 1800;">

        <div viewModel="@id('vm')" apply="com.eg.sample.zul.controller.sampleController">
            <label id="label" value="@load(vm.displayLabelName)"></label>
        </div>
    </window>
</zk>
```

Controller class : **sampleController.java**

```
package com.eg.sample.zul.controller.sampleController;

public class SampleController extends SelectorComposer<Component> {

    private String displayLabelName;

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) {
        try {
            super.doAfterCompose(comp);
            this.displayLabelName = "First Name";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info(e);
        }
    }

    public String getDisplayLabelName() {
        return displayLabelName;
    }

    public void setDisplayLabelName(String displayLabelName) {
        this.displayLabelName = displayLabelName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not mix MVC with MVVM. You don't need to extend the SelectorComposer

Answer (score 0):

**In a [MVVM ViewModel](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/ViewModel)**

You have to tell zk (i.e. the binder that synchronizes your view model and components) that the value has changed. [Have a look `@NotifyChange`](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/ViewModel/Notification#Notify_Bean_Change).

First put an annotation on your setter:

```
@NotifyChange("displayLabelName")
public void setDisplayLabelName(String displayLabelName) {
    this.displayLabelName = displayLabelName;
}
```

And then use the setter to manipulate the value:

```
setDisplayLabelName("First Name");
```

Now the setter will tell zk that the value has been changed, and zk will map it to the label.

As an alternative, you can manually notify (mentioned at the link as well):

```
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, this, "displayLabelName");
```

**In a [MVC Composer](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer's%20Reference/MVC/Controller/Composer)**

MVC in zk works very different: you do not control the values, but the components themselves. You do this by ["wiring"](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer's%20Reference/MVC/Controller/Wire%20Components) them into your Composer, which then manipulates them:

```
@Wire
private Label label;

@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) {
    try {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        setDisplayName("First Name");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.info(e);
    }
}

public String getDisplayLabelName() {
    return label.getValue();
}

public void setDisplayLabelName(String displayLabelName) {
    label.setValue(displayLabelName);
}
```

Comment: I want to bind the label name using controller class

Comment: @Ashwini Oh, you mean you want to use a composer and not a viewModel? I have added an example using MVC, and links to the documentation to get you started.

Comment: In doAfterCompose you could also do `self.setAttribute("name", "firstname");` Then you can access it in zul via zk expressions `<label id="label" value="${name}"></label>` but this solution is just one way. But it would decouple view from controller.

Comment: @Kani that sounds like an interesting approach, haven't used custom attribues much. You should add it as an a separate answer, sound promising!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do in `doBeforeCompose` use the  `self.setAttribute("name", "firstname");` to populate the value in the component scope of the current component of composer. Then you can access it in zul via zk expressions `<label id="label" value="${name}" />` but this solution is just one way. But it would decouple view from controller and it's much better from performance view, cause it doesn't hold bindings etc in RAM. If you need a view-only-way this one should be prefered.

Otherwise Malte's MVVM answer is the right way cause it's much better supported and the real "ZK Way" of doing stuff. But sometimes you are stuck in legacy versions and then this could help.